# Executing two celery workers from one line

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am working on a project for my university within a team where I was mostly working on the frontend and some basic django models, so I am not so familiar and eloquent with django-celery and I also did not set it up. At first we were using one celery worker, but I had to add one more so I was able to finish a user story.

I am currently running two workers with one in a terminal each like this:

```
exec celery -A my_proj --concurrency=1 worker
exec celery -A my_proj --concurrency=1 worker -B -Q notification
```

While i run those two my project works, but I need these to start from one line. So:
How do I get those two into one line for a script?

So far I've tried around this:

```
exec celery multi start celery -A my_proj --concurrency=1 notification -A my_proj --concurrency=1 -B -Q notification
```

But it stops my project from functioning.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

`celery multi start 2 -A my_proj -c=1 -B:2 -Q:2 notification`

The above tells start 2 workers with the 2nd worker to process the `notification` queue and embed celery beat to it

### Explanation

You can run the following to see the commands resulting from this

`celery multi show 2 -A my_proj -c=1 -B:2 -Q:2 notification`

Output:

```
celery worker -A my_proj -c=1
celery worker -A my_proj -c=1 -B -Q notification
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`exec celery -A my_proj --concurrency=1 worker && exec celery -A my_proj --concurrency=1 worker -B -Q notification`

Comment: It does not work for me. It seems like it only runs the first part, because when i change the order it runs the other part.

Comment: It doesn't work because when you execute the first part of this, celery runs attached mode so, second part doesn't work.